# How to post data to server with 2 different authentication in python

Tags: python, http-post, httprequest

How to post data as well as file to a server in python. This server uses 2 times authentication
Lets say,
When I try to post data and file to url2 = **www.example.com/submit_form.php** with authentication, I get **www.example.com/login_page.php** in response from the server asking for authentication.

How do I request url with two different authentications.
I can also provide both authentication to login_php but I don't know how to do it.

Here's the code:

```
path=<path_to_file>
url = 'www.example.com/submit_form.php'

values = {'description' : 'Life is beautiful',
          'Status' : 'Work in Progress' }

files = {'upload_file': open(path,'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD), data=values)
```

Response from Server:
Excerpt from response HTML page:

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="www.example.com/submit_form.php" name="login_form" >
    <input name="user_login" type="text" id="user_login" size="40"  />
    <input name="ldappass" type="password" id="ldappass" size="40"  onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13)do_check();">
    <input type="button" name="mySubmit" value="OK" class="button" onclick=do_check() />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think you can make **one** request for your 2 times auth. You should first authenticate to your first page, then to your second page. It's a two times process (and if some cookies or tokens were provided after the 1st step, just reuse them for the 2nd one)

Comment: how are you posting?

Comment: Check what is `socket` connections. Did you have any information about of `Ethernet packet` or `Ethernet Topology` ? Server can block you with single line code ! You need different IP and MAC basically(outbound).

Comment: No, I don't have any knowledge about **ethernet packet and ethernet topology**. Could you please post some example code. Really apprecuate it!